# Does meditation lead to incarnation?

Tags: meditation-insight, reincarnation

Continuous meditation will calm the mind, when eyes open there is a difference felt, this difference means the soul has change, is this change an incarnation ?
Similarly when hungry, thoughts are different & when satisfied with food there is relief, so this change from hungry to being relieved can be called an incarnation or change of soul ?

Answer (score 2):

Meditation leads to the clarity and tranquility of the mind, and such mind is fundamental and instrumental for discerning truths from non-truths.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is 'difference' or 'change' or 'transformation' of 'mind'.

Buddhism does not teach about 'incarnation' or 'soul'.

Possibly you are asking these questions on the incorrect forum.

Comment: Maybe the OP is asking about [becoming or birth](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/18353/254).

Answer (score 0):

The difference you felt is a temporary relief to your mind. Basically that happens because of the rate of thoughts coming to your mind became low. Naturally mind is full of thoughts. Mind runs here and there without taking any vacation. So after the meditation the feeling you get is normal because your mind became peaceful and concentrated. It is not a change of soul or incarnation. It is a behavior of mind which let you to further develop the meditation.